# Dynamically request permissions for Google Docs add-on

Tags: permissions, google-docs, google-docs-api, add-on

I'm writing an add-on that only needs to access the current document.
However, I would like to make it possible for the user to enable the add-on to access the content of other of his documents, on demand.

So far, to prevent the automatic inclusion of broader permissions, I tried to enclose my calls to `DriveApp`, e.g.

```
eval("Drive"+"App").getFileById
```

so that the authorization for DriveApp does not pop up at the installation screen.
As expected, when this line is executed, it fails.

How can I trigger the dialog box for asking further permissions?

Comment: As a method, how about adding a scope you want to use to the manifest (``appsscript.json``)? When GAS script is run after the scope was added, the authorization screen is opened and user can authorize the added scope. Because I'm not sure whether this is the method you want, I posted this as a comment.

Comment: I thought about this, but for new users it would always ask for all the permissions upfront, which I think is invasive. Add-ons should be able to ask for permissions on demand.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize my comment was not useful for your situation.